# Unable To Find Imported Jar File For Json ME In Blackberry JDE

Tags: blackberry

I imported the Json ME jar file
downloaded from "github"
into a blackberry project in which i will need to interpret
JSON responses from a web service.

The issue is that the project fails to compile
when it encounters this line:

```
import org.json.JSONObject;
```

And gives the error

```
  error: package org.json does not exist.
```

The name of the jar file is "json-1.0.jar"

How can i resolve this?.

Comment: How did you add the jar to the project?

Comment: Right clicked on the project,properties and then add jar file..in the BB JDE

Comment: Is the jar file listed in the .jdp file?

Comment: No its not...how can i rectify it?

Comment: Put the jar on a folder, e.g. in `lib`. Then add the relative file path (regarding .jpd file) under the `[Files`. Check this example, http://pastebin.com/dUhudC1K (not a complete .jdp file).

Answer (score 1):

As you have imported additional jar file, then you should get additional cod file when compilation finished. Seems that you have installed only application cod file without library cod file.

Look at the folder where your application cod file located. There must be additional cod file, related to org.json library. Sign this library and install it along with the application cod file.

If there is no library cod file exists in the compiled app folder, check your project settings. Seems that jar file has been added incorrectly or it is not accesible.

Comment: Make a folder lib inside your project folder and place jar file to this folder. Then specify this jar file as a library. If it does not help then add source code of this library to your project. You can get source code here: http://www.json.org/java/

Comment: Thanks for your time..i think my main issue now is how to refer to the classes in the jar file.The JSONObject class has a line in it..which reads "org.json.me"..but when i say import "org.json.me" in my code, i get an error saying it does not exist. How can i solve this?..also how can i add the source code to my project if the "library" method is unsuccessful?..thanks

Comment: From my point of view, if source code is available, then adding source code instead of adding jar file is preferred. So, do not add jar file, instead of that download all source java files and add them to your project. You can download source java files here: http://goo.gl/t81sZ

Answer (score 0):

Create folder called lib within your resource folder, copy and put the jar file in lib folder right click the jar Select Build Path-> Add to build path, then import the jar if you want to use in ur project It wont through module not found exception.